# Error on memcpy, length not correct

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am copying data in Gateway (contains the string `Oct/10/12`) to `dest_data` but `dest_data`is getting more characters than the source:

```
unsigned_8   *dest_data
int_16 len;      

len = (int_16)strlen( Gateway ); // len got 9 correctly
(void)memcpy( dest_data, GatewayApplicationRlsDate, len );
```

The final output of `dest_data` is `"Oct/10/1210.1.3"`

Do I have to clean the `dest_data` before copying?

Comment: Is this really C++, or is (as it looks) C?

Comment: On a semi-relate note, why do you store the string length in a 16-bit integer?  `strlen()` returns `size_t` and `memcpy()` accepts a `size_t`.  There's no need to cast, AFAICS.  What does casting to something other than `size_t` buy you?

Answer (score 6):

You copy your string content, but not the terminating null character. Add one to len, and you should be fine. But the proper solution would be to use `strcpy()`, which copies the trailling null character automatically.

Also, think to allocate memory for dest_data (`malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(*dest_data));`)

```
unsigned_8   *dest_data;
int_16 len;      

len = (int_16)strlen( Gateway ) + 1; 
dest_data = malloc(len * sizeof(*dest_data));
(void)strcpy( dest_data, GatewayApplicationRlsDate );
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `NULL` character.

Comment: Use of `strncpy` is safer programming practice. `strcpy` is vulnerable to buffer overflow exploits.

Comment: If strlen has just been used to determine the length, why would the 'proper' solution be `strcpy`? `strcpy` has to look at each character it copies to check for \0, but you already know where the \0 is so you are just wasting cycles.  `memcpy(dest, date, len+1)` is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

No memory has been allocated for `dest_data` (it is an uninitialised pointer) and the `memcpy()` is not copying the null terminator. Allocate `len + 1` bytes of memory for `dest_data` and copy `len + 1` to also copy the null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy len + 1 bytes

At the moment you forget to copy the null terminator `\0`.

When you try to acces the copy, the string functions search untill they find a `\0` which could be anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your strlen use the length from the GatewayApplicationRlsDate?

ie:

len = (int_16)strlen( GatewayApplicationRlsDate );

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strcpy`, this will also copy the trailing null byte.

```
strcpy( dest_data, GatewayApplicationRlsDate );
```

Of course all the caveats about handling raw pointers apply. Really you should probably be using `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`.